# Can I have some help setting up my document to meet the requirements of my Assignment?

Tags: formatting

• use font type Arial, font size 10 (minimum)

• line spacing should be single or no greater than 1.25cm

• margins should be set at 2.3cm

• all pages should be numbered (bottom footer right hand side) and include your student number (top header, right hand side)

• include a title page. This should include your name, student number and tutor’s name.

The assignment was clearly intended to be written in word, but I've written so much LaTeX at this point, that I feel more comfortable writing it. Does LaTeX even support Arial as a font? lol

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? If you are so familiar with LaTeX, you don't want to use Word, you presumably know enough to make a start and provide a minimal example. Is the title page meant to be numbered?

Comment: Please read the notes when adding tags. `format-files` are surely not relevant here.

Comment: *"...  but I've written so much LaTeX at this point, that I feel more comfortable writing it."* And you are asking how to modify the header and footer and create a title page? This question screams *Do it for me*. :-/

Answer (score 5):

The Helvetica font looks almost the same as Arial, so that may the easiest to use. It's what I used here. The font is rather large, so I scaled it down a bit by loading it with the `scaled` option. I also loaded the `mathptmx` and the `textgreek` packages in case you need some serif or Greek letters.

You can also play with the `\headrulewidth` parameter; set it to `0pt` in order to remove the rule entirely.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}

% font packages 
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=0.87]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[artemisia]{textgreek}

\usepackage[margin=2.3cm]{geometry}

% smaller section headings. You can use option 'tiny'
% to further reduce the size. 
\usepackage[small]{titlesec}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % Clear the header and footer
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[R]{007}

% if you don't like the rule at the top, set this to 0pt
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Another day in paradise}
\lipsum[2]

Some sans-serif text \textrm{next to serif} and some 
\textGamma \textrho \textepsilon \textepsilon \textkappa\
to illustrate that the different fonts have sort of similar 
size now. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you insist on using Arial rather than Helvetica, you should be able to do so using the xelatex engine. However, only font aficionados will know the difference, and they would not pick either of these fonts in the first place. I use the same ruse regularly and have never got caught. (Same for substituting Times Roman for Times New Roman).

Comment: I wouldn't change the baseline skip but, if you do, better to use `setspace`. The default single-spacing is probably good enough here (it will be more spaced out than Word's single.) Weird rule. Usually, everyone wants double-spacing.

Comment: You are right, @cfr, I didn't read carefully and assumed that it should be exactly 1.25 cm. Will update.

Comment: Seat Toledo (2012) and Skoda Rapid are also *almost the same*. But they are completely different products. So are Arial and Helvetica, even though one was supposed to be the clone of the other.